# Programmatically download php-generated web pages

Tags: php, dictionary, download

I need to download an online Hindi language dictionary for offline use. Every word in the dictionary has a php generated page. The URL for these pages is as follows:
`http://pustak.org/home.php?mean=X`, where X represents a number.

So the first word in the dictionary can be found by going to `http://pustak.org/home.php?mean=1`, the second word is `http://pustak.org/home.php?mean=2` and so on.

How do I programmatically download all of these pages and save them as separate html files?

PS: In case you're wondering, I'm doing this because I need a Hindi dictionary to refer to offline on my iPod Touch while travelling (since the Touch does not have cellular data). I've tried a whole bunch of Hindi dictionary apps and none of them even come close to this the quality and the definition-count of this free online dictionary. So my plan is to dowload the whole thing as html files, store them all in an iOS filesystem app that supports full text search and I have my own offline dictionary...

Help appreciated!

Comment: cURL and `file_put_contents` will be your friends.

Comment: what is the maximum value of mean?

Comment: Or maybe you can use an external tool. Like http://www.httrack.com for example.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach, I would personally use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

From the homepage:

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline
>   browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a
>   local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML,
>   images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack
>   arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a
>   page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the
>   site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can
>   also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted
>   downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help
>   system.

According to the website it supports Windows 2000 / XP / Vista / Seven and several flavours of Linux.

I assume you could then import the downloaded files into this iOS app you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `file_get_contents`:

```
$max = 100000 //total num of words to get

for($cont=1; $cont<$max; $cont++){
    $sourceCode = file_get_contents('http://pustak.org/home.php?mean=$cont');

    if(!file_put_contents('/path/word'.$cont.'.html',$sourceCode)){
        echo "error with word number".$cont;
        die();
    }
}
```